# Ignoring Nulls using Lag() in SQL Server 2018

Tags: sql-server, lag

I am trying to get the Activity ID linked to Dispatch. In the data Attrib_43 will only get populated if Dispatch is created.

What i am looking to do is to get the Activity ID of the previous row before the Dispatch created.

Attached is the code that i am using

```
 Select  sea.ROW_ID, sea.CREATED_DTTM,sea.SRA_SR_ID,sea.ATTRIB_43, tsk.CRT_DTS, tsk.TASK_DESC, datediff(ss,sea.CREATED_DTTM, tsk.CRT_DTS) as dd 

, seal.x_isp_notes, seal.x_isp_comments, seal.comments, seal.x_isp_agent_desc

, tsk.TASK_SUB_TYPE_CD, tsk.TASK_TYPE_CD, tsk.WHAT_ID

, cdl.ORIGIN_NM
,LAG(sea.ROW_ID,1) over (partition by sea.ATTRIB_43 order by sea.CREATED_DTTM) AS 'FLAGID'

--, tsk.*,

, fdc.FISCAL_QUARTER

from GSEDATA.dbo.X_ISP_EXTRNL_CASE_ID sea

join rawdata.corp_ww.FISCAL_DAY_CALENDAR fdc on sea.CREATED_DATE = fdc.ACTUAL_DATE

left join rawdata.svc_base.SFDC_TASK_DTL tsk on sea.X_ISP_EXTRNL_CASE_ID = tsk.TASK_ID

left join rawdata.svc_base.SFDC_CASE_DTL cdl on cdl.case_id = tsk.what_id

left join GSEDATA.dbo.s_evt_act_logs seal on sea.ROW_ID = seal.row_id

where --sea.ATTRIB_43 = '04391481876'
sea.SRA_SR_ID = 'A-2Q7YF57W'

order by sea.CREATED_DTTM
```

But it is not working as per my Expectation - Activity ID flag for Attrib 43 is coming as Null

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are getting null `FLAGID` for non- null `attrib_43` becuase you are using a `partition by sea.ATTRIB_43` clause.
Partition by divides the query result set into partitions. The window function is applied to each partition separately and computation restarts for each partition.
That is why the null values for `ATTRIB_43` are grouped into one window and the non-null `ATTRIB_43` will have a separate window for each distinct value, therefore giving a `NULL`  for `LAG()` function in the first row of each window.
you should remove the clause `partition by sea.ATTRIB_43` if you want lag values for all rows.

```
LAG(sea.ROW_ID,1) over (order by sea.CREATED_DTTM) AS 'FLAGID'
```

Comment: I got it right- As i was using the wrong column header. Thanks a lot for the help